# Finding the maximum price for a given customer id

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to write a hive query. I am working on a data set that has three columns : Customer ID, Product ID and the Price. I need to write a query which outputs the columns Customer ID and Product ID for the maximum item bought by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [customer], [product] FROM table WHERE [price] = (SELECT MAX(t.[price]) AS price 
FROM table as t WHERE t.[customer] = [customer])
```

Could be something like this if you're wanting to find the most expensive item that a customer has purchased? I'm unsure if the syntax is 100% correct but it should give you something to go from. I've added a cheat sheet below for Hive just incase.

[Hive Cheat Sheet](https://hortonworks.com/blog/hive-cheat-sheet-for-sql-users/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `row_number()`:

```
select Customer_ID, Product_ID
from
(select Customer_ID, 
        Product_ID, 
        row_number () over ( partition by Customer_ID order by Price desc) rn 
 from table
where customer_id=given_customer_id --add filter if necessary
)s
where rn=1;
```